# Atmel Studio Dummy_Handler

Tags: exception, arduino, interrupt-handling, atmel, atsam3x

Occasionally I will get an unexpected interrupt, and my code will hang inside **`Dummy_Handler()`** in `exceptions.c` of the Atmel Studio Framework (ASF).  I am using the ATSAM3X8E microcontroller of the Arduino Due.

```
void Dummy_Handler(void)
{
    while(1) {
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to determine **which interrupt** it was?

Of course I could replace this single handler with unique dummy handlers, one for each exception. (There are about fifty of them.)  For example change each line in the same exceptions.c file:

```
void HardFault_Handler  ( void ) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Dummy_Handler")));
```

to this

```
void HardFault_Handler  ( void ) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Dummy_HardFault_Handler")));
```

Etc...  Or try to reason how my code could have generated which interrupt.  But who has that kind of time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This MCU has an Interrupt Program Status Register that gives some clue as to source.  ASF has wrapped it in a function **`__get_IPSR()`** in core_cmFunc.h:

```
uint32_t phantomISR = 9999;

void Dummy_Handler(void)
{
    while(1) {
        phantomISR = __get_IPSR();
    }
}
```

Then this global variable can be monitored at runtime.  (In my case I paused the assembly code for this loop-of-death and saw the value 3 in the R3 register.)  The Atmel MCU doc explains its value:

```
ISR_NUMBER
This is the number of the current exception:
0 = Thread mode
1 = Reserved
2 = NMI
3 = Hard fault
4 = Memory management fault
5 = Bus fault
6 = Usage fault
7-10 = Reserved
11 = SVCall
12 = Reserved for Debug
13 = Reserved
14 = PendSV
15 = SysTick
16 = IRQ0
45 = IRQ29
```

Both times this happened to me it was the Hard Fault, a kind of blue-screen-of-death for the Ardunio Due.  So I also installed a **Hard Fault handler** of my own.

```
ISR(HardFault_Handler)
{
    while (1) {
    }
}
```

Also, detectable in debug mode by pausing.  Of course the sequel is, [what causes a Hard Fault](http://blog.frankvh.com/2011/12/07/cortex-m3-m4-hard-fault-handler/)?  I'm guessing memory wipe or infinite recursion.